# Origin of Hecke operators

Tags: nt.number-theory, reference-request, modular-forms, hecke-operators

What is the original paper in which Erich Hecke had first introduced the Hecke operators?

Comment: To be fair, Mordell had used "Hecke operators" in proving the weak multiplicativity of Ramanujan's tau-function, that is, of the Fourier coefficients of the holomorphic cuspform of weight 12.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Über Modulfunktionen und die Dirichletschen Reihen mit Eulerscher Produktentwicklung. I, Math. Ann. 114 (1937), 1-28; II, ibid., 316-351. These two papers are available [here](http://www.digizeitschriften.de/download/PPN235181684_0114/PPN235181684_0114___log4.pdf) and [here](http://www.digizeitschriften.de/download/PPN235181684_0114/PPN235181684_0114___log24.pdf).